# xslt 3.0 xml to JSON number format

Tags: json, number-formatting, xslt-3.0

I would like to convert the following xml to JSON:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<map xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions">
    <array key="ids">
        <number>3218087</number>
    </array>
</map>
```

using

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="3.0">

    <xsl:output method="text" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:value-of select="xml-to-json(.)" />
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This gives me:

```
{"ids":[3.218087E6]}
```

What I need is

```
{"ids":[3218087]}
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Cheers
Przemek

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The spec https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-xml-to-json for a `number` element suggests:

> An element $E named number results in the output of the string result
>   of xs:string(xs:double(fn:string($E)))

and the cast to `xs:string` requires the E notation for values greater than 1000000 I think (https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#casting-to-string).

So I don't think the `xml-to-json` result can be changed, unless a processor allows some options to choose a different formatting rule for numbers.